# Serialization of Dictionary embedded deep in object

Tags: c#, serialization

I have been trying to serialize a pretty big object. This object uses dictionaries in order to keep track of various data. I am using the binary formatter, and want to be able to easily serialize the whole object whithout interfering/having to change code in the below layers.

Is there any way fix to this? I don't want to serialize the dictionaries manually (as I've seen others do to solve this issue).

The one who solves this get the golden plate ;)

Comment: The binary formatter *can* serialize dictionaries, it's the XML serializer that chokes on them. Or do you want to exclude certain fields from binary serialization?

Comment: Okay.. That's odd. All I get when trying to serialize this dictionary is "cannot find MyObject constructor".. I probably missed to say that this is an extended dictionary(class that derives from Dictionary<int, list>). But inner exception points to DictionaryInternal... And I got a constructor so.. I'm quite lost on this one.

Se code below:

    [Serializable]
    public class MyObject : Dictionary<int, string>, ISerializable
    {
        public MyObject() : base()
        {
        }

        public List<int> GetIndexes()
        {
            return this.Keys.ToList<int>();
        }
    }

Comment: If you say ": ISerializable", you should implement ISerializable and this includes a special constructor which takes (SerializationInfo, StreamingContext). Do you really need to implement ISerializable in the first place?

Comment: Oh wait a second.. I also missed to mention the fact that it's possible to serialize the object.. (my mistake) Though, when it's when it's deserializing this object that the exception is thrown...

Comment: I tried to implement this earlier. Though cleaned up the code a little, so you can ignore the fact that ISerializable is "implemented".

Comment: This is just as expected, and means that the `private MyObject (SerializationInfo, StreamingContext)` constructor is missing. You must provide this constructor if you implement `ISerializable`.

Comment: Well, if I remove the interface, I still get the same error..

Comment: ...because Dictionary<> implements ISerializable itself. If you derive from Dictionary<>, you have no choice but implement ISerializable properly. Deriving from Dictionary<> is usually a bad idea anyway.

Comment: That's true. But I added:


public MyObject(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) {}

And now it works fine. So thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Anton, the binary serializer is capable of serializing all objects in your object graph, as long as each object in the graph is serializable. If you're having trouble diagnosing which objects in your object graph *aren't* serializable, you can use [sertool](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2007/01/sertool.html) to find this out:

[image]